# How to read an existing core data persistence store, without creating a new one?

Tags: swift, core-data, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a Core Data database to Realm. I'm okay with changing the APIs in my code (I actually did a whole rewrite of the app), but the problem is migrating the existing data stored on users' devices.

To read data from Core Data, I first create a `NSManagedObjectContext`, and set its `persistentStoreCoordinator` to a coordinator:

```
// app delegate, didFinishLaunching
var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
```

To create this `coordinator`, I do:

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "momd")!
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
```

Then at this point, I don't know what to do next. Normally in a Core Data app, I would add a persistent store at a desired URL...

```
let url = aDesiredURL.appendingPathComponent("MyPersistentStore.sqlite")
try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
```

...just like the Core Data boilerplate that Xcode generates for you when you check "Use Core Data" when creating a project.

However, since I'm migrating, I don't want to add a new persistent store. If there is already a "MyPersistentStore.sqlite" file stored at `aDesiredURL`, I just want to read from that.

From my experimentation, `addPersistentStore` seems to create a new MyPersistentStore.sqlite file if it doesn't exist, and read from it if it already exists, but I want a method to read from MyPersistentStore.sqlite if it exists, and *not create a new file* (maybe throw an error?) if it doesn't.

I looked through the methods of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` in its documentation, and found `persistentStore(for:)` which sounded promising. However, it returns nil whether or not the `.sqlite` file exist.

I also tried not doing anything after creating the coordinator, but that didn't work either: I wasn't able to retrieve any managed objects from the context (the fetch request returned 0 objects).

Code that fetches the entities for reference:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "MyEntity")
let managedObjects = try managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
print(managedObjects.count)
```

How can I only read from the `.sqlite` file representing the Core Data persistent store, without creating a new one?

Comment: You can add the store as read-only with the init options. Working out whether the store exists already is a file level query via NSFileManager. I.e if store file exists then boot up coredata and migrate else do nothing.

Comment: @WarrenBurton does creating a read only store not create a new file? I thought of using `FileManager`, but I thought it might not be the right thing to use, as it's a "lower level of abstraction" than Core Data. In my mind, it feels like querying Core Data with SQL statements, as if I'm breaking the abstraction. Or am I not?

Comment: Can't you check if it exist using `persistentStore(for URL: URL) -> NSPersistentStore?`? `coordinator.persistentStore(for: url)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, `persistentStore(for:)` just returns nil if I don't use `addPersistentStore`. I also checked the `persistentStores` property. It is empty too. They only return non-nil/are non-empty after I call `addPersistentStore`, but I don't want to call `addPersistentStore` because it creates a new `.sqlite` file... :(

Comment: I’m not sure if the file only creates on the first save. Then again it might create the tables when you add the store even if read only. If this is only a legacy data  migration task why wouldn’t you use the tool that fits I.e check for store existing. Old client data  won’t be there if the store isn’t.

Comment: @WarrenBurton So you mean I should use `FileManager` anyway? Oh well, that's fine as well... I guess.

Comment: I have a similar problem, only that my persistent store has for unit testing type `NSInMemoryStoreType`. How did you solve your problem?